# Trying to make a constant that is an UIImageurl in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

what I'm having trouble doing is making a constant that is a string of a uiimageurl in firebase. I stored the url in the firebase database.  and It looks like this:
[image]

in the previous versions of firebase and swift you were able to do that by just doing this:

```
let imageUrl = User.profileImageUrl
```

now this does not work and I need to find the updated version on how to do that. An answer is greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the image first. Then you will be able to get the url where the image is saved. Here is an example.

```
func saveButtonPressed() {
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "profile_images")

    let imageData = profileImageView.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)
    guard let data = imageData else { return }

    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    // Here you can decide where to save the image. In your case it will look something like this.
    // let ref = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "profile_images").child(user.uid)
    storageRef.putData(data, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
        if let _ = error {
            // Error Handling...
            return
        }

        storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            if let _ = error {
                // Error Handling...
                return
            }

            guard let url = url else { return }
            let urlString = url.absoluteString
            print(urlString)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

So if you want to get the url for an image that is already saved in storage. You first need the reference that it is located.

```
//Example as above
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "profile_images").child(user.uid)
storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            if let _ = error {
                // Error Handling...
                return
            }

            guard let url = url else { return }
            let urlString = url.absoluteString
            print(urlString)
        }
```

If there is no image located in the reference you will get an error. It's basically the same as the first answer I provided, but without the saving. Since the image already exist you can just use ref.downloadURL. Hope this helps.

Comment: This works, and thanks for this. The thing is I want to reference the image through different view controllers that I uploaded/saved them in. And I just need a way that I can get the string without transferring data between view controllers.

Comment: Do you want to get a reference to an image that is already saved into storage?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what I want. I should've been more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Also, to populate the image from Firebase I use this and it sounds like this would work for you...

```
func showProfilePicture() {
    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                let storage = Storage.storage()
                let storageRef = 
 storage.reference(withPath: "\(uid)/photos/\(0)")
                PhotoUploader.downloadImageUrl(from: 
 storageRef) {[weak self] (url) in
                    guard let url = url else { return }

  self?.displayProfileImage.downloaded(from: url, contentMode: .scaleAspectFill)
                }
    } else {
        showAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: "Not signed in")
    }
}
```